# what are the exact formulas for calculating the matrice elements Lo, Co, Ro, Go, Rs, Gd

Tags: resistance, capacitance, inductance, hspice, conductance

The following code is a hspice code. what are the exact formulas for calculating the matrice elements Lo, Co, Ro, Go, Rs, Gd? In other words, I want Lo, Co, Ro, Go, Rs, and Gd calculation formulas. thank you.

The following input netlist file shows RLGC input for the W Element:

````
W1 N=3 1 3 5 0 2 4 6 0 RLGCMODEL=example_rlc l=0.97
V1 1 0 AC=1v DC=0v pulse(4.82v 0v 5ns 0.1ns 0.1ns 25ns)
.AC lin 1000 0Hz 1GHz
.DC v1 0v 5v 0.1v
.tran 0.1ns 200ns
* RLGC matrices for a four-conductor lossy
.MODEL example_rlc W MODELTYPE=RLGC N=3
+ Lo=
+ 2.311e-6
+ 4.14e-7 2.988e-6
+ 8.42e-8 5.27e-7 2.813e-6
+ Co=
+ 2.392e-11
+ -5.41e-12 2.123e-11
+ -1.08e-12 -5.72e-12 2.447e-11
+ Ro=
+ 42.5
+ 0 41.0 + 0 0 33.5
+ Go= + 0.000609
+ -0.0001419 0.000599
+ -0.00002323 -0.00009 0.000502
+ Rs=
+ 0.00135
+ 0 0.001303
+ 0 0 0.001064
+ Gd=
+ 5.242e-13
+ -1.221e-13 5.164e-13
+ -1.999e-14 -7.747e-14 4.321e-13
.end```



Lo: DC inductance matrix, per unit length [H/m].
Co: DC capacitance matrix, per unit length [F/m].
Ro: DC resistance matrix, per unit length [Ω/m].
Go: DC shunt conductance matrix, per unit length [S/m].
Rs: Skin effect resistance matrix, per unit length [Ω/m√Hz].
Gd: Dielectric loss conductance matrix, per unit length [S/m.Hz].
````

Comment: Have you looked through the [user manual](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee140/sp12/labs/hspice_sa.pdf)?

Comment: Hi, Is there no answer to my question?

Answer (score 0):

The link provided in the comments points to HSPICE's user guide. At page 154 (194/1024) you'll see the description for the `W` element. The values are entered by the user, which means that these values are either calculated by the user, or provided based on some measurements, or datasheet. *How* you calculate these values is up to the user, since there is no formula to rule them all, they are all application-, and transmission-line-specific.

In other words, the user chooses to model a *certain* transmission line, and based on that, the values are chosen. So, what transmission line do you want to model? Does it have a datasheet? If yes, what does the datasheet specify?